# Points of interest for zip code

Tags: bing-maps, point-of-interest

I"m looking for way to get list of points of interests like airports, parks, etc. per zip code using Bing maps.  Believe me, I search google but it looks like my google is broken since I can't find anything useful. I just need a way to get that info.  If there is like a list that would be even better.  Any help is appreciated fellows. Is there a simple URL where I can pass in my bing map key, a category and longitude/latitude and get a list of point of interests?

Comment: Thank you for down-vote, your lack of comment is troubling, however.  Express yourself!  The camera loves you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NAVTEQ point of interest data sources that are in the Bing spatial Data Services here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478189.aspx

You can use the Query API to filter on the PostalCode property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx

Here is an example that gets points of interests that are in zip code 98004 and returns the results as XML:

```
http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs?&$filter=PostalCode%20eq%20'98004'&$top=250&o=xml&key=YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY
```

That said, make sure that your use case does not go against this restriction in the [Bing Maps terms of use](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html):

> (h)Use Content that consists of points of interest data to generate
>   sales leads information in the form of ASCII or other text-formatted
>   lists of category-specific business listings which (i) include
>   complete mailing address for each business; and (ii) contain a
>   substantial portion of such listings for a particular country, city,
>   state or zip code region.

Comment: First off, thank you!  I will take a look at your links.  Second, no siree....mostly looking for public places like parks, airports, bus stations ,etc.