# What API should I use on Android if I want to find the nearest, say, Wal-Mart to a given latitude longitude pair?

Tags: android, geolocation

I tried looking at the `Maps API` and Locations API, but neither seemed to have a format where you just make an `HTTP` call and get back some `JSON` objects indicating location.

Comment: There is nothing in Android itself for this. You need to use an outside service.

Comment: I recently had the same issue. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764139/points-of-interest-for-zip-code) for using a third-party

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's nearby search,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
sb.append("&radius=5000");
sb.append("&types="+type);
sb.append("&sensor=true");
sb.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
```

Pass the necessary parameters, and get it done by an `AsycTask`.

Please refer [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/) for more details.